# google sheets, the Assigned script disappears from drawing button when users click on it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a drawing on a sheet w title that says "SUBMIT".
It contains an assigned script code that says "Do_submit" which executes my apps script function called "Do_submit()".
When a user clicks it, the assigned script in the drawing eventually disappears.
Is this a google bug? Or a user issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, your function is improperly named. Rather than "Do_submit()", it should be named something like this: `funtion submitData()`.

Second, do you have a copy of your code that your referring to so that a proper answer can be given to your question?

(Hint: you can copy and paste the code into your response)

Comment: Thanks for helping. The do_submit was my changing the text for sake of simplicity. The code.gs is actually:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    function send_email() 
{
  var spr1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    blah blah    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress1, subject, message);   }  In the drawing button , the assigned script reads: send_email, and that's really all there's to it

Comment: Is there any reason why the assigned script randomly disappears from the drawing button?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar experience.I have create some buttons on google spreadsheet (insert > drawing) (save,modify, clear form etc). And those buttons have assigned to each script (Right click on button > Assign script). Each buttons running good.  Somehow, after running the script (for example click save button), the other button doesn't have assigned script. And it happens in other buttons randomly. Although the function name = submitData() , clearForm(), modifyRecord().

```
function clearForm(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheetForm = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TicketOrderForm");
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();          //create instance of UI to show alert
  var response=ui.alert("Simpan","Apakah form akan di hapus?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking user response
  if (response==ui.Button.NO){
      return; //exit from this function
  }

  activeSheetForm.getRange("C16").clearContent().setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  activeSheetForm.getRange("F16").clearContent().setBackground('#FFFFFF');

}
```

Comment: I guess the keyword here is "RANDOM"